# What is the match group syntax in Eclipse's search and replace

Tags: regex, eclipse, vim, replace

What's the syntax to perform a search/replace on Eclipse and use "match groups" (is that what it's called?)

On vi I do the following:

```
%s/log\(.*\)/log \1 debug/g
```

And lines like this one:

```
log "Message"
```

are replaced with:

```
log "Message" debug
```

What's the correct syntax for eclipse in the search/replace dialog box (beside checking up "Regular expressions")

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use $1 instead of \1

For the /g global replace flag, use the Replace All button:

[image: eclipse find/replace dialog]
<sub>(source: [bpsite.net](https://bpsite.net/misc/eclipse_replace.png))</sub>

Note: The above is the Find/Replace dialog for a single file, comes up for Ctrl-F

For working across multiple files, default shortcut is Ctrl-H, and the dialogs are a bit different:

[image: eclipse search & replace dialogs]

Comment: Then you may be interested in Vrapper, an Eclipse plugin that wraps around editors and makes them Vim-like. http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/
Doesn't do replacing, but still might be handy. :)

Comment: @Peter: I have tried vi plugins in some other tools but they only make things worst since then I don't know which tool am I. It interrupt my train of thought.

Answer (score 2):

In the Find Field: log(.*)

Int the Replace With Field: log$1 debug