# Eclipse regex find and replace

Tags: regex, eclipse

I need to find

```
<th>blah</th>
```

and replace with:

```
<td class="shaded">blah</td>
```

thank for the help...:)

Comment: Click on the tick symbol for the best answer to your previous questions

Comment: blah is just a string...any string

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question or the problem.  In Eclipse this will work just fine.

Comment: Can blah have any text in it?  Alpha Numerics?  Symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Replace All button.

You will find this screenshot from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095413/search-and-replace-on-eclipse/1095446#1095446) very useful.

[image]

Comment: Nice!  +1 for the screenshot still being new here, that's the first time I've seen it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another screen shot specifically for your situation:

[image]

This would be to replace within the current file you're editing.  You can use roadrunner's answer as a guide to do this globally.