# What is a regex to replace all "System.out.println()" with empty space?

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove all System.out statements from my code on eclipse.

example:

```
System.out.println("hello");
System.out.println("hello" +a);
System.out.println(1 +b12);
```

basically all `System.out` statements no matter what their parameter is.

I have to the following but it doesn't even come close

> System.out.println(.)*;?``

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7522068/2235132) answer.

Comment: Tricky. The statement may span multiple lines. The part to be printed can contain all kinds of stuff (think '"');"'). `System.out` may be called something else in some places.

Comment: Risky... imagine you have this statement: if (boolean) System.out.println(""); Removing the System.out line will cause a change it the way your program executes, possibly without even a compile error showing up!

Comment: @jimjim if you have lines like `if (boolean) System.out.println("");` you really need better coding conventions.

Comment: @stt-lcu I agree completely... but if you have a bunch of System.out.printlns in your code, I'm already thinking your conventions might be lax, so I wouldn't make any assumptions here!

Comment: Also, it still is very valid Java. And it's not a solution if it only works when your code follows a certain style, it should work for all java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following regex and simply do find and replace. There is a option for regex find and replace in `Eclipse`.

```
System.out.println\(([^;].*\)*);
```

I tested for following

```
 System.out.println("  ");
 System.out.println("  fdfdf");
 System.out.println(")  fdfdf");
 System.out.println(";");
 System.out.println();
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831692/eclipse-regex-find-and-replace) may help you to find regex find and replace in `Eclipse`

[Here](http://regexr.com?369oo) is regex online test. I put some data there. any one can test with any thing.

Comment: `System.out.println(";");`

Comment: @dognose ok. Thanks for pointed out. edited, now it will work for that too.

Comment: @Ruchira but only for that exact case. You only check for the ``;`` at the first position in the code. Try something like ``println(doStuff(3) + " returned; yay!");``

Comment: I think now it is fine

Comment: @f1sh I am sorry what are you saying?

Comment: Your regex (currently it's ``System.out.println\(([^;].*\)*);``, you seem to edit it frequently) makes no sense at all. Just test it with ``System.out.println("a;");``.

Comment: @f1sh I post a link specially for you. go there and test with any thing

Comment: I agree that the regex is funny :). 
For example, try `System.out.println("test"); doSomethingElse();` - the whole thing including the second method call would match your regex. 
And of course multiline is not supported...

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you could try to redirect System.out to somewhere else (or nowhere) using `System.setOut(somePrintStream)` at the top of your program.

If you are running in Eclipse, it will also let you specify where System.out should go instead of the normal console view (somewhere in Run Configurations).

And if this is to get rid of debug logging, consider replacing it not with nothing, but with calls to a logging framework. Then you can turn it on or off at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I would go the following (admittedly windy) route:

1. Create a class `my.domain.ReplaceHelper` with a `public static void helpMeToReplaceSysouts(Object obj) {}`
2. Search and replace `System.out.println` for `my.domain.ReplaceHelper.helpMeToReplaceSysouts` in the source code
3. Refactor: inline the `helpMeToReplaceSysouts` method.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you try this instead? It does the job as well!

In Eclipse, **CTRL+F** gives the `Find/Replace` window. In that give the below strings,

Find String - `System.out.println`
Replace String - `//System.out.println`

Hurray, you commented out all the sysouts!

Comment: Best solution :) (Beside multiline stuff - but this will result in syntax errors and can be fixed manually then.)

Comment: I would really not recommend it. You can change the logical flow of your program without realising. I have actually done this!

Comment: unless and until you use `System.out.println` for anything other than what its supposed to do, I don't see any harm, why you shouldn't use this.(As @dognose said, multiline stuff is the only potential problem, which can be manually fixed, as eclipse is smart enough to show those **red** lines!).

Comment: @jimjim how? did you have lines like `System.out.println("foo"); $this->callGodMethod();`?

Comment: @stt-lcu e.g. if (logout) <newline> System.out.println(""); <newline> a++;

Comment: It's not a programmatic solution -1

Comment: @vladkras-OP never mentioned that a programmatic solution is only required! This is just a quick fix alternate, which would work in most cases, unless there are formatting issues in the code or if the `if` block statements are not bound within braces!

Comment: @jimjim where are your curly braces? Never write an if without curly braces because it's dangerous (like in your example). Anyway, i see your point.

Comment: @stt-lcu yes you're right but sadly I've seen plenty of examples in the wild where this convention is not followed.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard for several reasons:

- Java, as most languages, is a Type 2 (context-free) language in the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). That means that there can be an arbitrarily complex statement in the `println` parameters, such as `println(doA(4+(-1))+format(");");` that makes it extremely hard to find the end of the `println` statement using a regex. The only reliable approach is to parse the code according to it's type 2 attributes (as [Brandon pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18735879/214525)) or to leave it to a tool such as eclipse's refactoring methods (as [R.J stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18735890/214525)).
- Following the regex approach, you might look for an start-of-line/end-of-line thing, such as `^\s*System\.out\.println\(.*);\s*$`, but that will not catch multiline-`println`-statements
- You won't find a regex to catch all the possible cases of what the parameter could be like.

Overall: [Thilo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18735781/214525) is the best choice. Although that means your code has to already be written accordingly.

Comment: "Although that means your code has to already be written accordingly." Redirecting System.out somewhere should work reliably.

Comment: I agree, sorry. I had your "calls to a logging framework" in mind, which is clearly the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to escape the parentheses
2. The asterisk should follow the dot immediately to mean "any number of any characters"
3. You should avoid the `.*` to catch your entire program, so use some delimiter that doesn't appear in your output-statements like for example `;`

To sum it all up I would use something like

```
System.out.println\([^;]*\);
```

Comment: What if i do ``println(";");``?

Comment: Then you're in trouble ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to ignore the brackets. Only thing that IS Sure, is that the statement will end with ";" and most likely (depending on code style) with a new Line.

without line-delimiters, `.*?` has a good chance to match anything you would NOT match.

```
^System\.out\.println.*?;\s*$
```

Comment: ``println`` statements can span over multiple lines. It's ugly, but it does happen a lot.

Comment: See my edit. If you have something like this, there is no save way to cover everything.

Comment: ..which is exactly why this problem cannot be solved elegantly using regular expressions. The problem is that using a regex-replace on code which contains multiline-``println``-statements leaves you with non-compilable code.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the other suggestions will get most of them, but they will mostly ignore several pedantic cases, such as SomeOtherSystem.out.println, or "this string contains a System.out.println()" or even "class System(){ public Someting out; ...}; System.out.println("this isn't what you think it is");

Ultimately, you can't 100% perfectly reason about Java with regular expressions alone. It sounds like you only want to remove them from your own code base this one time, so just use this and check up on the results.

If you wanted to really automate this properly (for instance, if you wanted to build a tool to do this), I'd suggest that you use a real Java parser, like this one: https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/

Answer (score -2):

Try this: `System.out.println\(.*?\)`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/HgMCb/) for those who doesn't believe (it's written in JavaSscript, not Java, but the same pattern will work everywhere)

**EDIT** This regexp: `/System\.out\.println\((?<=\().*(?=\))\)/` removes all inside matching brackets: **[JSFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/s7v-mt0)**

Comment: `.*?` ... You will replace a good portion of your code with that one :D

Comment: @dognose: No. The question mark makes it non-greedy. So it will stop at the first closing parens.

Comment: @hsz really? http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/HgMCb/ and stop downvoting if you're not sure

Comment: @vladkras Really: http://jsfiddle.net/HgMCb/1/ - However I didn't downvoted your answer.

Comment: @vladkras this doesn't work because you are matching ) inside the argument to println, potentially.

Comment: as @hsz pointed out, this regex will match until the first closing parenthesis. If there's one in the parameters (such as a function call or in the string literal), this will not work. So the "stop downvoting if you're not sure" is quite cocky.

Comment: I just answer to exact question of *codefish*. Why are you escaping `"` or putting another `(` inside? [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/HgMCb/2/) works. Where is the problem? You just answering your own questions in your own comments.

Comment: If you are just having the original examples in mind, then you should change your approach of developing software. Expect the unexpected.

Comment: The original question was to replace all system.out calls.  Nothing in OP indicates that output strings with parantheses can be discounted. Nor can you discount `System.out.println(someobject.toString())`

Comment: @Taemyr @f1sh this `/System\.out\.println\((?<=\().*(?=\))\)/` does all the work, stop yelling & look [my edit](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/s7v-mt0)

Comment: I have removed my downvote.  However I feel I have to point out that `/System\.out\.println\((?<=\().*(?=\))\)/` is a difficult way of writing `/System\.out\.println\(.*\)/`